# Identify the page being shown while in The Loop

Tags: loop, pages

In my loop, I'm trying to set it so that certain text is displayed on certain pages, if there are no posts to display.

I thought this would be simple, using `is_post()`, but it seems that this function does not work when you are in The Loop.

Does any body know how I can identify the page that is currently being shown, whilst in The Loop?

The below code is from `loop.php` - it's how I have the code structured, as the content is not important in this instance. However, for those interested, here is my full `page.php` and `loop.php` code - http://pastebin.com/hDjR6C7A.

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Do stuff here -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php if(is_page(162)) : // Careers ?>

        <!-- Do stuff here -->

    <?php if(is_page(716)) : // Partnerships ?>

        <!-- Do stuff here -->

    <?php elseif(is_search()) : ?>

        <!-- Do stuff here -->

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: in what template are you using your code? i.e. does your theme have page.php, search.php, and index.php, etc ?

Comment: is that all the code of your loop or does the template contain a custom query?

Comment: You appear to be missing an `endwhile` in your code.

Comment: @Patj - Not missing, I just accidentally deleted it for this example code. Added back in now.

Comment: @Michael - This in my `loop.php` file. The Loop is used by various templates to display posts, and in the case of two pages, and the search, I need to show some text if there are not matching posts. I've updated with a link to Pastebin that contains my full code for `page.php` and `loop.php`. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to get the meaning of 'if there are no posts to display' - as this would usually only occur in index or archive pages; when you get to a static page, it is kind of difficult for it not to have a 'post' which is the page itself. do those referenced pages have page templates with custom loops? btw: does your code work for search results?

Comment: @Michael - I have a custom search Class to handle searches, which outputs to `search.php` (using `loop.php` - `the_template_part('loop', 'index')` - to display the posts). If you look in the Pastebin, you notice that I have set two functions that tell the page what it needs to do in certain situations. So for Careers, for example, the page will output the title and content, and then query any posts of type `career`, before using `loop.php` to output them. The issue comes in that while in `loop.php`, if there are not `careers` to show, I can't use `is_page()`, as it doesn't work in The Loop.

Comment: 'and then query any posts of type career, before using loop.php' - with that query, you are affectively destroying the 'page' information; you could try to check for the used 'post_type' in your conditional statement (?).

Comment: @Michael - Good point about it being destroyed. I'll see if I can knock something up for checking the post_type and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael - I've resolved this by adding a 'no_post_id' attribute to the `$page_atts` array, and then checking this at the relevant point of `loop-index.php`. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). That will return information about the page *per se* and not necessarily about the posts/pages being displayed in the Loop.

Be aware that it returns very different information depending on the type of page you are one. It will return user information on an author archive, for example, but category information on a category archive, and sometime it returns `NULL`.

### Related

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98138/21376

Comment: Good idea, but returns NULL in this case. `get_queried_object_id()` then returns `0`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try `is_single( $page_id )` instead. Basically is_post() has been deprecated.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is not what I'm looking for. The description even specifically notes that this is not for use for post type 'page'.