# Post-ID in url differs from $post->ID

Tags: posts, sidebar, id

I've got a page with a blogroll in the left column and a sidbar in the right one. When I try to retrieve the page-id inside of the sidebar like:

```
echo $post->ID;
echo get_the_ID();
```

The result is **3726** but the page URI is **page_id=3722** ! I'm really confused now. I badly have to catch the real page id to be able to use custom fields (with the right values).

EDIT:

I just noticed that 3726 is the id of the last blog element being displayed. But how to grab the page id?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99545/21376 I'd mark that duplicate if the system would let me.

Comment: Thank you for the link but this post you mention does not explain anything to me nor delivers it a solution - I've checked. So could you please explain why this question should be related? I don't see the relationship. And maybe you've got an idea what my problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identify the page being shown while in The Loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99534/identify-the-page-being-shown-while-in-the-loop)

Comment: @s_ha_dum That's one way of getting upvotes ;)

Comment: `$post->ID` and `get_the_ID()` both give you ID of the current post in the Loop and not necessarily the ID of the page you are on. `get_queried_object` always gives you information about the page. Your edit confirms my suspicion that the other question is a duplicate, whether you recognize it or not.

Comment: When I have too many loops in one page i tend to wp_reset_query() after each loop. That way you can still echo $post->ID; and get the original page id.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get what you need. One is mentioned in [Identify the page being shown while in The Loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99534/identify-the-page-being-shown-while-in-the-loop):

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
```

Unfortunately, this might break. `get_queried_object_id()` looks in the global variable `$wp_query` for the ID, and that variable can be overwritten during the page rendering by `query_posts()`. The same is true for functions like `is_page()`.

But you can fetch the real post ID earlier, during `template_redirect`, store its value, and get it in your widget class.

First we need a helper function that collects the post ID for later usage:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'collect_real_post_id' );

function collect_real_post_id()
{
    static $post_id = 0;

    if ( is_singular() && 'wp_head' === current_filter() )
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

    return $post_id;
}
```

And now you can use that value wherever you want, for example in your `widget()` method:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget
{

    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
        $post_id = collect_real_post_id();

        if ( ! $post_id ) // 0 evaluates to FALSE
            return;

        // do something with the post ID
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution - no doubt this will certainly work but I don't like to mess around to much in this theme ... that is not mine. Your hint with 'this might break' helped me to take an other mind road to an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually get_queried_object_id() should do this trick but it's not storing the proper page id - like toscho mentioned it might break.

There's an easy ways around this problem and I always prefer the easiest possible solution. So I came around with this one.

1. I switched the permalink settings to 'pagename'
2. Now my url's are
   like that: `http://www.mypage.com/examplepage/` and I can use now the
   uri without the slashes to feed the method `get_page_by_path()`

The resulting code:

```
function get_page_real_id_by_uri()
{
    $uri =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $uri = str_replace("/", "", $uri);
    return get_page_by_path($uri)->ID;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's possible in Wordpress (I'm new to it) to declare two same path names - this might be a weak point of this solution. But so far it works perfectly.

Comment: This will fail with child pages.